# Max file size for Image uploads for inclusion in a post?

Tags: discussion

I have been looking at the images posted and noticed that some are quite large and these (correct me if I am wrong) are added with *descriptions of the image* and not *embedded* in the page.

Is there an acceptable *image file size* for posts or any size is ok and is handled by the system ?

Comment: There is a maximum file size limit for uploading images to imgur. Is that what you mean? Or are you referring to image dimensions?

Comment: size is what I mean and you know that size ?

Comment: @George Takes all of ten seconds to click the image item in the toolbars; the system indicates the max file size per image.  I've included this information below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The max **file size** for a given image being uploaded is listed on the image upload popup:

[image]

As you can see, the max file size is 2MiB (which is just about 2MB total).

Image dimensions, I don't know if there's such a restriction, you'd have to ask Imgur.  But file *size* limit is 2MB.  I don't know if Imgur has a dimensions restriction, but 2MB doesn't leave for much in terms of super 'high resolution' files.

---

As noted in comments, this is only a restriction if using the StackExchange embedded Imgur upload system.  If you upload something to your own imgur account, or run it from your own web server, you are not bound to that 2MB image file size restriction.

Comment: extremely useful answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is onlya restriction on the `stack.imgur.com` host. If you host an image on your own Imgur account, and then link it, it can be any size.

Comment: In my experience, really high resolution images (4000x4000-ish) are accepted but they are recompressed as low-quality JPEGs.